Focusable items of LazyRow in Jetpack compose
I intend to write an app for Android TV using Jetpack Compose. I have a LazyRow containing several items. I want the background color and border of an item to change when it is hovered over. However, when I move quickly between items, I encounter the following error:
LayoutCoordinate operations are only valid when isAttached is true
Code:
@OptIn(ExperimentalTvMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun MainScreen(
    mainViewModel: MainViewModel = viewModel()
) {

    val isLoading by mainViewModel.isLoading.collectAsState() 

    if (isLoading){
        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(top = 16.dp), contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ){
            Box(modifier = Modifier
                .size(40.dp)
                .background(
                    color = Color.White,
                    shape = CircleShape
                )
                .padding(all = 8.dp)
            ){

                CircularProgressIndicator(
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary
                )
            }
        }
    } else {

        LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 16.dp)
        ) {

            items(mainViewModel.homeSections.size) {
                Section(homeSection = mainViewModel.homeSections[it])
            }
        }
    }
} 


@Composable
fun Section(homeSection: HomeSection) {

    var selectedItem by remember { mutableIntStateOf(-1) } 

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(bottom = 16.dp)
    ) {
        Row(
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Start,
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {

            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .width(8.dp)
                    .height(32.dp)
                    .background(
                        color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary,
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(
                            topEnd = 80.dp,
                            bottomEnd = 80.dp
                        )
                    )
            )

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(16.dp))

            Text(
                text = homeSection.name,
                style = TextStyle(
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.W700
                )
            )
        } 
 
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(16.dp)) 

        LazyRow {
            items(homeSection.posts.size) {
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .width(120.dp)
                        .height(200.dp)
                        .background(if (selectedItem == it) Color.Gray.copy(alpha = 0.3f) else Color.Transparent)
                        .border(
                            width = if (selectedItem == it) 2.dp else 0.dp,
                            color = if (selectedItem == it) MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary else Color.Transparent
                        )
                        .onFocusChanged { f ->
                            if (f.isFocused) selectedItem = it
                            else if (selectedItem == it) selectedItem = -1
                        }
                        .focusable()
                        .clickable {}
                        .padding(
                            top = 8.dp,
                            start = 8.dp,
                            end = 8.dp
                        )
                ) {

                    AsyncImage(
                        model = homeSection.posts[it].thumbnail,
                        contentDescription = "",
                        contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .height(140.dp)
                    ) 

                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp)) 

                    Text(

                        text = homeSection.posts[it].title,
                        style = TextStyle(
                            fontSize = TextUnit(
                                12f,
                                TextUnitType.Sp
                            )
                        ),
                        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                        maxLines = 2,
                        overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

How can I solve this problem?
